# VPS keeps hanging but I can't tell how

Tags: windows-server-2012, hanging

I have a VPS in a data center which hosts my websites, emails and software projects.

The issue is, it keeps hanging and I don't know how to debug as I'm not skilled enough in server management.

The data center provide an interface where I can restart the server, but I'm doing this at least daily, some times a few times a day.

The Windows 2012 server (DataCenter) is up to date with Windows Update.

The event viewer isn't that helpful: My server went down at around 12:35am as per the screen shot

[image]

However, it doesn't show any events.

BlueScreen viewer doesn't show anything

The Security tab possibly shows something odd, I don't know if the server is shutting down due to invalid logins (if it's being throttled). As you can see from this screen shot, there were many failed logins (actually the Audit Failure went on for hours).

The Data Centre have said it's my issue although I guess the cause could be outside the scope of my VPS?

Is there anything I can do to find out why server keeps restarting?

[image]

Comment: Your problem may also be hard disk related, if the hard drive is at the end of its lifetime, it may fail to write/read, causing the disk controller to wait for long timeouts, try checking the SMART data of your hard drive